# How to fix: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register()?

Tags: php, php-7.3

I have a website which I need to move but it seems that it doesn't work with PHP7.3.12 due to some old PHP funtions and the old 5.x is not an option this time :(

Firstly I had an error:

> Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register()
>   instead in /var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/in_site/autoload.php
>   on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sg_load() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/in_site/core/libraries/sql.class/sql.class.php:2
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/in_site/autoload.php(83):
>   require_once() #1 [internal function]: __autoload('SQL') #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/in_site/config.php(70):
>   spl_autoload_call('SQL') #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/index.php(14):
>   include_once('/var/www/vhosts...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/in_site/core/libraries/sql.class/sql.class.php
>   on line 2

I fixed the line 3 by changing it from `__autoload($ClassName)` to `spl_autoload_register($ClassName)`

Which caused me a new error:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in **/var/www/vhosts/dddd.eu/bbbgg.cdddd.eu/in_site/autoload.php** on line **129**

Here is the whole code of autoload.php - https://pastebin.com/1Qj3pFPH

What can cause this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I just look at your code I notice that you use `__autoload` as the name of your callable autoload function. I would not use that name since it has been used in the past, and might, as you discovered, trigger a deprecation error. You also cannot replace it by `spl_autoload_register` because that is an existing PHP function. So try this:

```
<?php

 function myAutoload($ClassName) 
 {
   .... code ....
 }

 spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');
```

It can also be useful to check the PHP manual for [spl_autoload_register()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: Thank you, it might be a part of the issues. I just discovered that other files of whole website are compiled by SourceGuardian, and it might be the another reason because I need to install a decompiler.